# How to generate a 2D-array from a String input? (SudokuSolver project)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, sudoku

Im trying to make a SudokuSolver where the sudokupuzzle is read in as a string which consists of dots(.) and numbers.

**Creating the setBoard() method:**

*The text should contain nine lines with nine characters on each line. Each row ends with the row end character \ n. Characters that are not numbers should be interpreted as empty squares. The setBoard method
should check that the text has the correct number of lines and characters. It should also check that the problem given is legal, ie. that each number occurs only once per row, column or block. Should something be wrong, the setBoard method should generate an exception of the type IllegalArgumentException with an appropriate error message.*

String input example:
3...8.......7....51..............36...2..4....7...........6.13..452...........8..

Im having a hard time getting this puzzle into a 2D-array which is why i've come here! I have kinda managed to get the puzzle into a normal array, but i'm not sure how that even helps. Kinda lost here...

Here is the code i've got so far, tell me if i need to provide more information!

```
public void setBoard(String input) {

    if (input.contains(".")) {
        String newInput = input.replace(".", "0");

        String[] rows = newInput.split("\n");

        System.out.println(newInput);

        int[] arr = new int[rows.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {

            arr[i] = Integer.valueOf(rows[i]);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not creating a 2D array. 
`rows[i]` is a String, not an Integer.

[check this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/)